# DropdownListFor value not setting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

[image]I'm am dealing with a problem in Razor View. DropDown is working fine but the selected value is not setting properly. The value is set from the controller but in the view @Html.DropDownListFor value is not setting. Any help will be highly Appreciated. Thanks in Advance! Here is my Code.

**View:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.BranchID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-2 col-form-label" })
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BranchID, new SelectList(Model.listofBranch, "BranchID", "BranchName"), new { @class = "form-control m-input", @id = "BranchID" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BranchID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
mdlGRN.BranchID = obj.BranchID;
return View(mdlGRN);
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you edit your question to show how you set listofBranch.  Also have you checked the value you are assigning to BranchID, if so what is it?

Comment: I am setting the values for listofBranch from the Db That's working fine. Also BranchID is Int and is also correct its just not getting set on any of the Editor Except for @Html.Display

Comment: I'm not suggesting it isn't working fine. But I still think it would be helpful to see what you are putting into your drop-down. For example if it was an array of strings that would explain why your value isn't populating.

Comment: I have added the screenshot describing there is value for BranchID in it. I'm getting all of this data from the database using a List.

Comment: I've tested your code with some test data and it works for me.  What is the html for your select that is sent to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

In the view code the selected value is not specified, when you are calling:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BranchID, 
                              new SelectList(Model.listofBranch, "BranchID", "BranchName"), 
                              new { @class = "form-control m-input", @id = "BranchID" })
```

There is no value passed to the `SelectList` Constructor to indicate the `SelectedValue`

It should be something like this asuming that the value you want selected is the one saved into the model:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BranchID, 
                               new SelectList(Model.listofBranch, "BranchID", "BranchName", Model.BranchID), 
                               new { @class = "form-control m-input", @id = "BranchID" })
```

Comment: Thanks for your support But this didn't solve my problem

Comment: Actually I have a value in Model.BranchID but still its not getting set.